# Whats wrong with this php code?Can anyone help me

Tags: php, html

I used this below code in www.codeacademy.com online php editor. It doesnt print  my desired output. Please show me where I have made mistake

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type= "text" name="num">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
        <p>
          <?php
          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          {
             $type=$_POST['num'];
             echo "$type";
             }



          ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the page to update automatically when the user puts something in the form? That won't work like that in this situation.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested it on my apache server , working just fine. just store the code in index.php and call it with http:// not file://

Comment: Can you try it on this site and let me know what causing this error            http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/2?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

Comment: i have no idea why it is not working on that site , but if you put it on a local apache2 , it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo $type instead of echo "$type";

If it doesn't work then replace action="index.php" to action = ""